# Multiple errors with Package Control in Sublime Text 3

Tags: linux, sublimetext3

I have installed Sublime Text 3 (unregistered, version: 3103 linux x64).

Now I want to install Package Control.

I tried to do this by paste the  [code](https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st3) into the console.

But I had the follow error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Next, I tried to manually install Package Control, but when I click the Preferences > Browse Packages… menu. But I saw the next:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SpmA.png)

What I should do to fix it?

p.s. there is no 'package_control' in the 'ignored_packages' setting

Comment: why such an old version of ST? recent versions allow you to install Package Control from the Tools menu.

Comment: I have installed sublime according to https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html.  I thought it is the latest free version. Am I wrong?

Comment: those repositories should give you the latest version - in fact, I heard they *only* have the latest version, which, looking at https://www.sublimetext.com/3, is 3176. So possibly something went wrong when you added the repository and a older repository source you had previously set up was used instead.

Comment: no, I completely removed the old one like that http://tipsonubuntu.com/2017/05/30/install-sublime-text-3-ubuntu-16-04-official-way/ and I deleted the folder ../.config/sublime-text-3

Comment: did you remember to "Ensure apt is set up to work with https sources:" using `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https` ?

Comment: Yes, did it. All like that https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html